# How can I delete select items from a text file?

Tags: java

For example, If I have a text file that has the following information:

```
2017-01-02 Joe Goldberg - 1320 Deerborne Lane, Los Angeles
```

How is it that I can remove everything except the Address? (essentially everything before the " - " )

Comment: Yes, there is a way. [Why is “Is there a way to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273/202153)

Comment: What are you asking? How to modify a text file? How to find last word in a line? Something else? What exactly is preventing you from writing the code yourself, using examples available on the web?

Comment: *"How is it that I can ..."* You can do that because Java can read text files, write text files, and change the strings of text read from the file before writing it back.

Answer (score 1):

Here is 2 lines of code to do it:

```
Path file = Paths.get("file.txt");
Files.write(file, Files.lines(file).map(s -> s.replaceFirst(".*?(\\S+)$", "$1")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to do so but the easiest would be to iterate through the lines of the file and for each line take a substring from 0 to lastIndexOf "-".